# How can I convert a 220v outlet to a 110v outlet?

Tags: compressor

I have a 220 volt pond aerator compressor that I'm going to replace with 110 volt unit.

Can I wire and keep the same power cord with the 6-15 plug and receptacle and just swap out the 220 connection to a 110 breaker at the panel?

Or do I need to go with a 110 to 220 adapter for the outlet?

Or do I need to configure everything from the compressor to the panel as 110?

Comment: Could you just use a step-down transformer and not worry about the wiring or receptacles?

Comment: Are you in the U.S.? If so, you mean 120/240. It's been the standard since the post-WWII era.

Comment: A pond aerator is technically a compressor, but unlikely to give you much trouble with startup loading, as it's probably a regenerative blower (or other fancy fan), not a piston-pump, and as such is not particularly hard to start (as folks will assume based on experience with piston-pump tanked air compressors.) With a running load of 5.8 amps it should start & run fine on 120V-15A.

Comment: Do you know if the existing wiring to the receptacle box includes a neutral?  If you're lucky it does, and you can have both a 240 v receptacle (hot/hot) and a 120 v (hot/neutral) in the same box.

Answer (score 2):

6-15 is hot-hot-ground. You want hot-neutral-ground for 120.

Will need to change the wire connections at the panel and the plugs/receptacle to ones made for 120 volts.

Will also depend if the compressor marked amps/watts are the same or different. Higher amperage might need to change the cable to a larger gauge. A 120 volt compressor will require 2x the amps than a 240 compressor for the same power/watts.

You should have a double 15 amp breaker for that circuit and probably 14 gauge wire.

Will need to see if the 120 volt compressor will work on only 15 amps.

Comment: The reason I was asking is the 240v compressor's bearings went bad and I want to replace with the same model but they are on 2 month backorder.  I can get a same brand 120v compressor to install for now, and then later swap it back out for the 220v model and keep it as a backup.  The 120v compressor pulls 5.8 amps (220v 2.5a).  If switching all the wiring configurations back and forth is the way to go then that's what I will do.  I'm guessing/hoping the 120v compressor (which runs continuously, no on/off) will be okay on the existing 15 amp breaker and not trip at startup surge.

Comment: Might be okay to just change from hot-hot to hot neutral at the panel and add the right sockets Harper suggests.  The 6-15 for a 5-15, then switch back if you get a new 240 compressor.

Comment: Maybe this is a stupid comment by  me, but isn't there simply a 120 volt outlet already available?  Even if not nearby, a heavy duty extension cord could be used.  5.8 amps is not a heavy draw. If possible, that would avoid having to fiddle with the outlet and wiring in the panel.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson - pond aerator - so quite possibly not. May be quite far from any other electrical installation. And it's really not difficult to move the white wire (assuming cable) from hot to neutral and swap the receptacle. 30 minutes or less should do it, and no extension cord to have to work around for months. For this load, there really isn't any obvious reason to switch back to 240V until the new compressor fails, tbh.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  Sorry, I missed the part about it being a pond aerator, thought it was just a compressor for a shop. Anyway, you're of course right...just move one of the wires from hot to neutral and swap out the outlet so it can only be 120.   Thanks for the comment. +

Answer (score 1):

There are trade-offs among the options you gave in the question. Typically "what should I do?" is off-topic because it depends on your priorities, skills, and aesthetic preferences.

In this case, assuming you have the common priorities of 1) works well 2) meets codes and safety rules and 3) standard, easy for future owners of the property to understand then you should **Change the receptacle to 110 as well as moving wires at the breaker panel for 110v.**

This will work as long as the wires to the receptacle are large (thick) enough, you can easily look up tables for wire gauge vs power carried vs distance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the secret.

[image]

Some of the most dangerous and cringeworthy installations happen when someone does not realize the correct socket for the job *exists*. The right thing is in "the next bin over" at the store, and costs a few dollars. As you can see, they all fit the same boxes and cover plates.

So the answer is, when you rewire the circuit for 120V, change to the 120V socket that matches the circuit.

By the way, "changing to a 120V breaker" is unnecessary. You can simply leave the hot wire on the 240V breaker that it is on, and move the neutral to the neutral bar.  The 240V breaker is simply two 120V breakers glued together, with an internal mechanism added for common trip.

Comment: Your answers are normally _extremely_ detailed, and I've come to anticipate a fair bit of what you're going to say next. However, I've got to admit, this one has left me a bit lost. Are you suggesting simply replacing a `6-` outlet with a `5-` outlet?

Answer (score 1):

No, NEC 406.4(F) says on a premises with multiple voltages receptacles of different voltages can't be interchangeable with each other.

The NEC requires outdoor 120v receptacles be GFCI protected, until the latest edition of the Code protection was not required for 240v receptacles, so you need to either buy or add a 120v GFCI breaker or a 120v GFCI receptacle. If you use a GFCI receptacle then you can use just one leg of the 240v breaker.

Also there is an issue that #12 or #14 wire the neutral wire must be a white (or grey) wire. If currently fed by UF cable with the white remarked then if you can remove the marking then you can use it as a neutral. If fed by conduit neither wire should be white, and remarking a hot colored wire as white is not permitted, so you would need to replace or add a white wire.